# replace full string in xpath just get before

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I am searching a solution to remove a string value obtained on a webpage with an XPath function.

I have this :

```
<div id="article_body" class="">
  This my wonderful sentence, however here the string i dont want :
  <br><br>
  <div class="typo">Found a typo in the article? <a href="typo.php" title="Typo Correction" rel="shadowbox;width=530;height=470;">Click here.</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So at the end I would have

> This my wonderful sentence, however here the string i dont want :

I get the text with

```
//*[@id="article_body"]
```

Then I try to use replace:

```
//replace('*[@id="article_body"]','Found a typo in the article? ', )
```

But it doesn't work, so I think it's because I'm a newbie with XPath...

How can I do that please?

Comment: *"How can I do that"*... Do what? What is your exact desired output? Note that XPath allows to *select* node, but not to *remove* or *replace* something

Comment: The replace() function would work in XPath 2.0, but my guess is that you are using an XPath 1.0 processor. Also, you need to supply an empty string '' as the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are getting the [computed string value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of the selected `div` element.

> The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order.

If you don't want to include the `text()` from the descendant nodes, and only want the `text()` that are immediate children of the `div`, then adjust your XPath:

```
//*[@id="article_body"]/text()
```

Otherwise, you could use [`substring-before()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring-before):

```
substring-before(//*[@id="article_body"], 'Found a typo in the article?')
```